# Getting values from 2 tables with different conditions for both tables

Tags: mysql, sql

Table 1

| ID | FirstName | LastNmae | city | Group | code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | john | smith | abc | E | P |
| 21 | don | davis | def | E | P |
| 3 | vee | miller | ghi | Q | P |
| 6 | vee | miller | ghi | Q | P |

Table 2

| ID | FirstName | LastNmae | city | Status | EmpName | Phone |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | john | smith | abc | U | Company 1 | 123 |
| 21 | don | davis | def | P | Company 2 | 456 |
| 3 | vee | miller | ghi | C | Company 3 | 789 |
| 4 | jim | jones | xyz | P | comapany4 | 001 |

I have 2 tables mentioned above. I need an output from both table under these conditions

For table 1 condition is:
`Group='E' AND code='P'`

For table 2 condition is : `Status = 'U' OR Status = 'P'`

For output required columns are:
`ID, FirstName, LastName, City, EmpName, Phone`

I cannot use UNION because number of columns mismatch.

Desired Output:

| ID | FirstName | LastNmae | city | EmpName | Phone |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | john | smith | abc | Company 1 | 123 |
| 21 | don | davis | def | Company 2 | 456 |
| 4 | jim | jones | xyz | comapany4 | 001 |

How can i get desired output. With UNION i can't get "EmpName" and "Phone" column. Is there anyway to use JOIN to get desired output.

Comment: This should be an easy ask, but it's more difficult than it should be because you haven't normalized your data.  Your tables' columns  apparently overlap almost completely in the two tables.  You should ask yourself the question, why is it in two tables in the first place?.  Typically data like this is organized inside a `person` table, and then relationships like person-to-company, person-to-group, person-to-status *could* be in different tables as appropriate for their 1-to-1, 1-to-many, or many-to-many relationships with companies etc.  Then your query could join users, groups, and statuses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you still need `UNION`. Try this query:

```
SELECT ID, FirstName, LastName, city, EmpName, Phone
FROM table2
WHERE Status IN ('U', 'P')

UNION

SELECT t1.ID, t1.FirstName, t1.LastName, t2.city, t2.EmpName, t2.Phone 
FROM table1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
WHERE t1.Group = 'E' AND t1.code = 'P'
;
```

Comment: He needs `UNION` for many reasons. A standard `JOIN` would return the data in columns, and the OP wanted the data in rows. I don't know why people refuses to use `UNION`, instead of be gratefull to have an operator that solves their problems...

Answer (score 0):

First, your results are all coming from `table2`, so this returns the results specified in the question:

```
select t2.ID, t2.FirstName, t2.LastName, t2.city, t2.EmpName, t2.Phone
from table2 t2
where t2.status in ('U', 'P');
```

I think you also want a matching condition on `table1` (which is not needed for your example).  Based on your description:

```
select t2.ID, t2.FirstName, t2.LastName, t2.city, t2.EmpName, t2.Phone
from table2 t2
where t2.status in ('U', 'P') or
      exists (select 1
              from table1 t1
              where t1.id = t2.id and
                    t1.Group = 'E' and t1.code = 'P'
             );
```